# A better way of passing parameters to a TADOStoredProc (Delphi)

Tags: sql-server, delphi, stored-procedures, ado

I am needing to convert a large amount of SQL queries into stored procedures. I have some code that updates about 20 or 30 values at one time in one Delphi procedure. I can handle creating a stored procedures to do such a thing. The problem is my way to pass parameters to stored procedures is very bulky like this:

```
    with stored_procedure do......
    Param := Parameters.AddParameter;
    Param.Name := '@SSN';
    Param.Value := edtSSN.text;

    Param := Parameters.AddParameter;
    Param.Name := '@FirstName';
    Param.Value := edtFirstName.Text;

    Param := Parameters.AddParameter;
    Param.Name := '@LastName';
    Param.Value := edtLastName.Text;

    Param := Parameters.AddParameter;
    Param.Name := '@UserRID';
    Param.Value:= GetRIDFromCombo(cbUser);
```

I also am not sure if that causes a memory leak(is it necessary to free such TParameter objects?)

Anyone have a better way of handling a large amount of parameters? (I can not use a new library. I must use ADO, and the SQL I use is MSSQL) (also, I'm NOT using ADO.net)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This doesn't cause a memory leak.  stored_procedure will clean up its parameters.  You can confirm this with FastMM by adding the following to your .dpr:

```
  ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True;
```

First, I'd get rid of the "with" statement.  It can lead to more problems and less readable code.

I'd create a helper method that accepts a stored procedure, a parameter name and a parameter value, which will make your code more manageable.

```
AddParam(stored_procedure, '@SSN', edtSSN.text);
AddParam(stored_procedure, '@FirstName', edtFirstName.Text);
AddParam(stored_procedure, '@LastName', edtLastName.Text);
AddParam(stored_procedure, '@UserRID', GetRIDFromCombo(cbUser));
```

Answer (score 20):

There's an accepted answer :-), but I want to point you to simpler and easier way to define and use the parameters with one line :

```
stored_procedure.Parameters.CreateParameter('SSN',ftString,pdInput,30,edtSSN.text);
```

It's simple and flexible, because you can define the input and output parameters with same line.

and from Delphi help:

```
function CreateParameter(const Name: WideString; DataType: TDataType;
    Direction: TParameterDirection; Size: Integer; 
    Value: OleVariant): TParameter;
```

Comment: This appears to be a better answer than mine.

Comment: Thanks Bruce & Rob, That's the beauty of SO, I have learned many things for Delphier here, and trying to share what I know with others :-)

Comment: That is quite handy, though I still prefer the first way as it is simpler for a large amount of only input parameters

Answer (score 11):

ADO will create the parameters for you, you just need to call Refresh on the parameters object:

```
 SP.Connection := SqlConnection; // must be done before setting procedure name
 sp.ProcedureName := 'MyStoredProc';
 sp.Parameters.Refresh; // This will create the parameters for you as defined in SQL Server
 sp.Parameters.ParamByName('@SSN'').Value  := SSN; // params now exist
```

etc

If any parameters are output you will need to set them explicitly:

```
   sp.Parameters.ParamByName('@ReturnValue').Direction := pdInputOutput;
```

Comment: This is nice but it is working only if procedure is in connection's default database. There is a bug in ADO that destroy parameters if you use DifferentDatabase.Owner.ProcedureName

Comment: I have also found that .Refresh does not always work, even within the same database.owner. I have not found any pattern to when it works and when it doesn't, but when it doesn't I get and error like "Parameter '@SearchText' not found." when I use .ParamByName. That same call works 99.9% of the time. Adding params manually seems to bypass the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was having troubles with parameters of type TDate and TDateTime, because sp.parameters.refresh creates parameters with dataType of WideString instead of TDate.

Answer (score 0):

This is the shortest I know:

```
stored_procedure.Parameters.ParamByName('@SSN').Value := edtSSN.text;
```

Note, you need to assign the `stored_procedure.Connection` and call  `stored_procedure.Parameters.Refresh;` before doing this