# Passing SQL Server stored procedure parameter names via Delphi

Tags: sql-server, delphi, stored-procedures, parameters

I'm new to Delphi and trying to find my way around calling some stored procedures in SQL Server.

This is the code I have been working with at the moment and it works....

```
FConnection := TADOConnection.Create(nil);
FMetaDataSP := TADOStoredProc.Create(nil);
LoadDBSettings;

FMetaDataSP.Connection := FConnection;
FMetaDataSP.ProcedureName := 'Messaging.ListMessageSections';
FMetaDataSP.Parameters.CreateParameter('@ReferralID', ftInteger, pdInput, 4, null);
FMetaDataSP.Parameters.CreateParameter('@ConsumerID', ftInteger, pdInput, 4, null);

Dataset := FMetaDataSP;
FMetaDataSP.Parameters.ParamByName('@ReferralID').Value := ReferralID;
FMetaDataSP.Parameters.ParamByName('@ConsumerID').Value := ConsumerID;
```

.... but when I do a profile in SQL Server I see this is the SQL that is executed.

```
exec Messaging.ListMessageSections 1,1
```

What I want is this instead...

```
exec Messaging.ListMessageSections @ReferralID=1, @ConsumerID=1
```

so that the ordering of the parameters in the code base are not important.

Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [A better way of passing parameters to a TADOStoredProc (Delphi)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159489/a-better-way-of-passing-parameters-to-a-tadostoredproc-delphi)

Comment: not really,.. at least not from where I am sitting... if I use the Parameters.Refresh method I get "exec Messaging.ListMessageSections 1,default,1" as the call to SQL not the named version of the parameters.  Of course this may be something that Delphi does not do.  I know .Net does but Delphi is new for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can do what you want if you use TADOQuery instead of TADOStoredProc.

```
FMetaDataSP := TADOQuery.Create(nil);
FMetaDataSP.Connection := FConnection;
FMetaDataSP.SQL.Text := 'Messaging.ListMessageSections @ReferralID=:ReferralID, @ConsumerID=:ConsumerID';

FMetaDataSP.Parameters.ParamByName('ReferralID').Value := ReferralID;
FMetaDataSP.Parameters.ParamByName('ConsumerID').Value := ConsumerID;
FMetaDataSP.ExecSQL;
```

Comment: Thanks for that. No other way you know of using the TADOStoredProc?