# Parameter of stored procedure not found

Tags: sql-server, delphi, stored-procedures, ado

I use the following code to call my stored procedure using `TADOStoredProc` type

```
MySP.Connection := aConnection;
MySP.ProcedureName := 'dbo.UpdateErrors';
MySP.Parameters.ParamByName('@Error_Number').value := -1;
MySP.Parameters.ParamByName('@NewError_Name').value := 'errorM1';
MySP.Parameters.Refresh;

MySP.ExecProc;
```

The parameter `@Error_Number` is part of the stored procedure `UpdateErrors` using SQL Server Management Studio, I add snip image for confirmation

[image]

but I can't understand why I get an error

Comment: Try to call `MySP.Parameters.Refresh` *before* you set the parameters. Or create theses parameters in your `TADOStoredProc` without calling `Refresh`. e.g. `MySP.Parameters.CreateParameter('@Error_Number'...)` (or create them in design mode)

Comment: Kobik, you should make this an answer.

Comment: I not sure about that `@` in their names.

Comment: Nice painting man! Red, and hand-crafted for optimal effect. I'm appreciating it.

Comment: @TLama -- @ should be before parameter name. tested. really.

Comment: Can you added `MySP.Prepared := True` instead of `MySP.Parameters.Refresh;` ?

Comment: still Problem is unsolved ;  no Change MySP.Prepared := True or  MySP.Parameters.Refresh;  directly  placed after Name Setting  LOC

Comment: no effect MySP.ProcedureName := '[dbo]..functionname' or   MySP.ProcedureName := 'functionname' without [dbo].

Comment: Can you use the Sql Profiler to see exactly the command you are sending? It might give you some leads.  Also there is a name mismatch on the second parameter '@NewError_Name' in code while in db it is '@New_Name'

Comment: @Liviu :  the param writing is correct, my post is in correct because I changed  from  used names  in the real application  to a public Version  with modified names

Comment: @user1769184, `"I changed from used names in the real application to a public Version with modified names"` In that case please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31903397/edit) your code.

Comment: @user176918 Have you tried the suggestions from kobik ? Could you please edit your post so it looks exactly like you code, I mean fix the parameter name and put "MySP.Parameters.Refresh" at the position where it is in your code. Like this it is hard for us to know what you tried or did not tried and thus makes it hard for us to help you

Comment: I really don't see why you can't resolve this by now... BTW, From my testing, letting ADO retrieve the parameters from the server via `Parameters.Refresh` can be bogus + the extra trip to the SQL server. I would construct the parameters programmatically like I explained in my first comment. see more information: [A better way of passing parameters to a TADOStoredProc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159489/a-better-way-of-passing-parameters-to-a-tadostoredproc-delphi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use a TADOCommand

```
  MyCommand.Connection := aConnection;
  MyCommand.CommandText := 'EXEC dbo.UpdateErrors :Er, :Na'; //you can call the params what you want
  MyCommand.Parameters[0].value := -1; //Or you can do ParamByNname and use Er and Na (or whatever you called your params) instead of indices
  MyCommand.Parameters[1].value := 'errorM1';
  MyCommand.Execute;
```

If you want to fix your code

Do

```
 ErParam := MySP.Parameter.Add;
 ErParam.Name := '@Error_Number';
 ErParam.DataType := ftInteger; //put your correct type here
 ErParam.Direction := pdInput; //set your direction for the param
```

etc. Lots more work... do the first way with ADOCommands

Comment: what is the type of ErParam ? ErParam : TCollection did not work for me.

Comment: `ErParam` is of type `TParameter` if you choose to go down the path of declaring the parameters.

Comment: @kobik not sure why you felt you needed to edit and add the `EXEC`, its not strictly needed in case of a single sp in a command.

Comment: @jasper You can rollback my edit if You are sure of that. Make sure you test it. Did not work for me without EXEC and separator between the parameters

Comment: @kobik. Thanks, your edit is fine. Just wanted clearer motivation. EXEC is more prudent and probably was needed in this case because schema was specified.

Answer (score 0):

The most common case is: the user connected to database hasn´t permissions for execute the procedure. You must grant it