# List of stored procedures inside a database

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I suffer the correct calling data to one of my databases ([Parameter of stored procedure not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31903397/parameter-of-stored-procedure-not-found))

For further debugging it might be helpful to extract a list of available stored procedures inside my database and the params to call each procedure.

How to get this information from the database using Delphi code?

- DELPHI XE 2
- Database SQL Server 2008
- ADO

Comment: What server back-end are you using, and which Delphi components are you you using to access the database?  You should add the same info as in your earlier q regarding these ...

Comment: The syntax to query stored procedures depends entirely on the database.  For example, with MSSQL you might use `SELECT [Routine_Name] 
FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[ROUTINES]
WHERE [ROUTINE_TYPE] = 'PROCEDURE'`

Comment: This question has absolutely nothing to do with Delphi. It's strictly a MS SQL Server SQL question. The same query against system databases would work in Delphi or any other language capable of using ADO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query will list all user defined stored procs (including their parameters and parameter types) in your default database:

```
SELECT
  sp.name,
  p.name AS Parameter,
  t.name AS [Type]
FROM
 sys.procedures sp
  LEFT JOIN sys.parameters p
    ON sp.object_id = p.object_id
  LEFT JOIN sys.types t
    ON p.system_type_id = t.system_type_id
WHERE 
  is_ms_shipped = 0 
ORDER BY
  sp.name
```

Put that into an ADOQuery object and set it to Active. (Updated answer with LEFT JOINS so that it includes SPs without parameters).